# Deleting an NSManagedObject from a managedObjectContext

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I have a `UITableViewController` set up that displays my `managedObjects` properly when it's loaded, however when I go to delete a cell my app crashes. This is what the console has to say:

```
    2015-05-03 09:55:20.125 MyApp[9461:663817] *** Terminating app due to 
uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update:
 invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing
 section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in 
that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or 
deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
 rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

When I reboot the app and go to my `TVC`, the object that I deleted the last time is deleted.

I have sections set up in my `NSFetchedResultsController` that is instantiated when `viewDidLoad` is called. I suspect I have a small issue, but I'm not sure where to go to add the missing line(s?).

I enable swipe to delete in `viewDidLoad` with this line:

```
// Enable swipe to delete
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = NO;
```

Here's my `commitEditingStyle`:

```
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete selected NSManagedObject from managedObjectContext
        NSManagedObject *objectToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:objectToDelete];
        [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];


        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView endUpdates];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
}
```

Thank you for reading. If you have any ideas, I welcome them.

Comment: Are you using the FRC delegate methods?

Comment: Yes. Turns out I had some redundant code and I was attempting to delete the same thing twice. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is saying that number of row returns from `numberOfRowInSection` is not matching with current number of item in table.. 
when you use `fetchedResultsController` `numberOfRowsInSection` should look something like this.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count];
}
```

and `fetchedResultsController` delegate `didChangeObject:` is then called automatically which calls the `deleteRowAtIndexPaths:` inside.. so you don't need to call the `deleteRowAtIndexPaths:` just call `deleteObject`, **otherwise it deletes twice.**

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple! I learned something, too!